# Dapper - find items in list that are not in table

Tags: c#, sql-server, dapper

I have a list of IDs (dynamically generated), and I want to find which of them do not exist in a table.

I'm using Dapper and Microsoft SQL Server.

Dapper allows IEnumerable parameters to be passed into queries and used as variables, which is nice, but I can't seem to wrangle it to work for the scenario of selecting things from that list.

Here is my code, showing two things I attempted (both of which do not work), and the Attempt3 which is the ugly solution I am contemplating (would perform poorly).

```
using Dapper;
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;

namespace DapperTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var connectionString = $"Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True;";
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                //Here's my overall problem:
                // Assume a table X exists with a lot of rows in it.
                // Now I have a list of IDs, which IDs in that list are not in table X?
                //Note: I will spoof X with a CTE in each query. Also, the IDs are uniqueidentifiers in the real table, 
                // but I'll use ints for this simple demo.

                Attempt1(con);

                Attempt2(con);

                Attempt3(con);
            }
        }

        //This fails because I cannot select from the @Ids parameter (what I would like to do, but syntax does not support it)
        //System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near ','
        static void Attempt1(SqlConnection con)
        {
            int[] idsToCheck = new[] { 1, 42, 112 };
            string sql = @"
                WITH X(Id) AS (SELECT 112 UNION SELECT 200)
                SELECT * FROM @Ids 
                WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT Id FROM X)
            ";
            try
            {
                var result = con.Query(sql, new { Ids = idsToCheck });
                Console.WriteLine("Attempt2: " + string.Join(",", result));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Attempt1 - " + e.Message);
            }
        }

        //Here I tried to stuff the list into a table variable and then select from it.
        //Fails with this error:
        // An enumerable sequence of parameters (arrays, lists, etc) is not allowed in this context
        static void Attempt2(SqlConnection con)
        {
            int[] idsToCheck = new[] { 1, 42, 112 };
            string sql = @"
                DECLARE @Tmp TABLE ([Id] int);
                INSERT INTO @Tmp VALUES (@Id);

                WITH X(Id) AS (SELECT 112 UNION SELECT 200)
                SELECT Id FROM @Tmp WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT Id FROM X)
            ";
            try
            {
                //note I pass in an IEnumerable directly as the second param
                var result = con.Query(sql, idsToCheck.Select(i => new { Id = i }));

                //but in the "Execute" context the below call works just fine - but I can only get back an affected row count from Execute (this frustrates me).
                //var result = con.Execute(sql, idsToCheck.Select(i => new { Id = i }));

                Console.WriteLine("Attempt2: " + string.Join(",", result));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Attempt2 - " + e.Message);
            }
        }

        //This works but is *very* undesirable because it fetches back a lot of data (everything in X).
        static void Attempt3(SqlConnection con)
        {
            int[] idsToCheck = new[] { 1, 42, 112 };
            string sql = @"
                WITH X(Id) AS (SELECT 112 UNION SELECT 200)
                SELECT Id FROM X
            ";
            try
            {
                var allIdsInX = con.Query<int>(sql, null);
                var result = idsToCheck.Except(allIdsInX);

                Console.WriteLine("Attempt3: " + string.Join(",", result));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Attempt3 - " + e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems like the job for a stored procedure with a table value parameter.

Comment: yeah, a table valued param might be the way....it seems like a lot of code overhead for what feels like a simple problem though. I'm hoping there's a simpler way.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean by overheard, could be taken a couple different ways. Performance wise though it's almost certainly the fastest method. In the general case at least.

Comment: @asawyer, by overhead I mean that I have to write up more code for the table var type, for the sproc, and manage permissions for the sproc (deployed differently in our code), etc. Not a performance concern, just my own laziness concern (that and it is not generic, so if I need to do it for another table, I assume that'd be a new sproc).

Comment: I tend to always have a few standard TVPs in my database, such as single-column int, short and long varchars, guids, and a few two-column combinations of the above. That covers most of my use cases without extra coding for each query. @asawyer You don't need a stored procedure to use a TVP

Comment: @Charlieface Sure but it would throw quite a few benefits like compilation and caching of the sproc, Sql security mechanisms, reuse among applications, ect ect. But yeah not required.

Comment: @asawyer Regards compilation: erm no, ad-hoc batches are compiled once and cached the same as sprocs *as long as there is no change to the batch* aside from parameter values. I'll give you the other points.

Comment: @Charlieface Oh yeah your right I completely forgot about that. Cool beans.

Answer (score 0):

@asawyer, @Charlieface - here's what the TVP solution ends up looking like. More code that I'd like, but not terrible. If I make a few PLACEHOLDERListTableType table types for different ID types (UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, INT, whatever), then treat those as "standard", I guess I can call it reusable.

I still would like a more reusable solution that doesn't require custom types to be created in each db I use it on. So I'll not mark this the answer. I'm hoping someone knows some Dapper/SQL trickery that could solve this more simply.

```
/*
    Created this table valued type, now try using it.
        CREATE TYPE [dbo].[IntListTableType] AS TABLE 
        (
            [Id] INT NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
        )
*/
static void Attempt4(SqlConnection con)
{
    int[] idsToCheck = new[] { 1, 42, 112 };
    string sql = @"
        WITH X(Id) AS (SELECT 112 UNION SELECT 200)
        SELECT Id FROM @Ids WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT Id FROM X)
    ";
    try
    {
        var result = con.Query<int>(sql, new { Ids = GetIntListTableValuedParameter(idsToCheck) });

        Console.WriteLine("Attempt4: " + string.Join(",", result));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Attempt4 - " + e.Message);
    }
}

static SqlMapper.ICustomQueryParameter GetIntListTableValuedParameter(IEnumerable<int> ids)
{
    var dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
    foreach (var id in ids)
    {
        dt.Rows.Add(id);
    }
    return dt.AsTableValuedParameter(" [dbo].[IntListTableType]");
}
```

Comment: Personally I think this will remain the best method. Perhaps you could setup some kind of reflection based thing that uses the properties of a class to create a datatable, there are examples online. By the way, your CTE can be simplified to `WITH X AS (SELECT * FROM (VALUES(112),(200)) v(Id))` or you could embed the CTE direct in the query

Comment: Even if I did that reflection-generated-datatable, the table type would still have to have been created in the db, right? That's the part I don't like.

Comment: Yes, but then stored procedures are also in the DB, there's nothing wrong with that. I suppose you could have the DDL for the table type in the client and it checks at startup if it's been created already, but not sure that's such a good idea.